# Using javascript var in JSP map as key

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc, jsp

I am running the following test javascript code inside a JSP file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selection = $('#selectedMonth').val();
    console.log(selection);
    var tableHead = "<thead><tr><th> ${javaMap.get(selection)} </th></tr></thead>";
}
```

where `javaMap` is passed to JSP with `modelandview.addObject("javaMap", map);` from the controller.

the issue I am running into is:
I run the following code and it works fine and displays the correct result:

`var tableHead = "<thead><tr><th> ${javaMap.get("Jan-2019")} </th></tr>
</thead>`

but when I run the one above it doesn't work at all. I tried to do console.log on the var, the value displayed in the logs is the same as `Jan-2019`

Any idea why map.get() works with hardcoded strings but not javascript var

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a front-end technology. This means the JS code that you wrote will be executed by your browser.

But, JSP code is executed on the server-side.

This is the issue with your code: JSP is executed first on server -> then js executed in browser. Therefore you never get the output you need.

"selection" is set after JSP tries to evaluate the following EL expression.

Consider getting the entire data from JSP itself using JSP tag Library (JSTL).. Look into it..

or

you can use an ajax call if you need to process data according to front-end/user inputs.